# Android Proxy Cursor

Tags: android, database, cursor, proxy-classes

I have a database with which I wish to expose data with a ContentProvider. However, it is important that all the colums are not exposed, and also they should be renamed. Is there any good way of doing this? I was thinking maybe some kind of proxy-cursor which takes a cursor and translates its columns to the desired ones, and calls to close and the like would just be replayed to the original cursor. Does something like this exist, or would it be hard to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any good way of doing this?

You could either implement a [`CursorWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) that filters stuff out, or copy the data into a [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

Comment: And, of course, this assumes you can't simply handle this via a properly-constructed query on the database. You can rename columns in result sets and skip columns in a SQL query.